# Invalid option 3 for cat

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I am trying to run the below Script it says invalid option 3 for cat..Whats the problem?
I am tried to use index file which specifies which file is ham and which is spam...to read the files and train spamfilter

```
#!bin/bash
DirBogoDict=$1
BogoFilter=/home/gunna/Downloads/bogofilter-1.2.4/src/bogofilter
x=0
for i in 'cat index | fgrep spam | head -300 | awk -F "/" '{print$2"/"$3}''

do
     x=$((x+1)) ; echo $x


cat  /home/gunna/Downloads/db-6.1.19.NC/build_unix/ceas08-1/$i| $BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -s

done

for i in 'cat index | fgrep ham | head -300 | awk -F "/" '{print$2"/"$3}''


do
     x=$((x+1)) ; echo $x


cat   /home/gunna/Downloads/db-6.1.19.NC/build_unix/ceas08-1/$i | $BogoFilter -d $DirBogoDict -M -k 1024 -n

done
```

Comment: Also note that you should use `grep -F` rather than `fgrep`. From the [grep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) `Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.`

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
 'cat index | fgrep spam | head -300 | awk -F "/" '{print$2"/"$3}''
```

needs to be in back-ticks, not single quotes

```
`cat index | fgrep spam | head -300 | awk -F "/" '{print$2"/"$3}'`
```

And you could probably simplify it a little with

```
for i in `fgrep spam index | head -300 | awk "/" '{print$2"/"$3}'`
```

Comment: While correct neither this nor the original is safe with spaces or shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

Kdopen has explained the error you got , here is the improved code for similar for-loop function.

```
DirBogoDict=$1
BogoFilter=/home/gunna/Downloads/bogofilter-1.2.4/src/bogofilter

awk '/spam/&&++myctr<=300{print $2 FS $3}' FS="/" index |while read i
do
    cat  /home/gunna/Downloads/db-6.1.19.NC/build_unix/ceas08-1/"$i"| $BogoFilter -d ${DirBogoDict} -M -k 1024 -s
done

awk '/ham/&&++myctr<=300{print $2 FS $3}' FS="/" index |while read i
do
    cat  /home/gunna/Downloads/db-6.1.19.NC/build_unix/ceas08-1/"$i"| $BogoFilter -d ${DirBogoDict} -M -k 1024 -s
done
```

Comment: Almost. The original did `head -300` *after* `fgrep`, so you want `awk '/spam/&&++myctr<=300 {print $2,$3}' ...`. And it is slightly briefer to just `print $2 FS $3` and then you needn't set OFS.

Answer (score 0):

**Also** look at your file names , since cat is giving an error and an option is invalid. To demonstrate this, Let say you have a file a name `-3error`

executing the following command

```
cat -3error
```

will gave

```
cat: invalid option -- '3'
```

cat therefore is thinking the "-" is followed by one of its command line arguments. As a result you probably get an invalid option error.